# If $Q\trianglelefteq G$ is a $p$-subgroup and $P\leq G$ is a $p$-Sylow subgroup then $Q\leq P$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $Q$ be a normal $p$-subgroup of a group $G$. If $P$ is a $p$-Sylow subgroup of $G$ how can I show that $Q\leq P$?

**Obs.:** I conjecture I'll have to use the following results:

**(i)** If $P$ is a $p$-Sylow subgroup of a group $G$ and $g\in G$ has order a power of $p$ and $gPg^{-1}=P$ then $g\in P$.

**(ii)** Every two $p$-Sylows subgroups are conjugate.

**Sketch:** If $x\in Q$ then $x$ has order a power of $p$ hence for showing $x\in P$ it suffices showing $$xPx^{-1}=P$$ by $(i)$. Since $xPx^{-1}$ is a $p$-Sylow of $G$ there exists $g\in G$ such that $xPx^{-1}=gPg^{-1}$ so that $$P=g^{-1} xPx^{-1} g.$$ Now I don't know how to move on, I thought it was a trick like adding and subtracting things but that didn't work out.

However, up to now I didn't use the normality of $Q$, maybe that will solve my problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can show directly that any $p$ subgroup $Q$ is contained in some conjugate of a Sylow subgroup $P$ ( the standard proof).

Consider the action of $Q$ on the set $G/P$, $(q, \bar g) \mapsto \overline{q\,g}$. Since $Q$ is a $p$-group the orbits have size $1$ ( fixed point) or divisible by $p$. Therefore, the size of the set of fixed points is congruent to the size of the set:  $|F| \equiv |G/P| (\mod p)$. Since $|G/P| \not \equiv 0 (\mod p)$ we conclude $F\ne \emptyset$
that is for some $g$ we have  $Q \cdot \bar g = \{\bar g\}$ and therefore $Q \subset g P g^{-1}$.